# Pass a callback to DropdownButton onChanged property

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a new Stateless Widget for later reuse

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JumpDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final int val;
  final Function callback;
  const JumpDropdown({Key? key, required this.val, required this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      value: val,
      onChanged: (int? newValue) {},
    );
  }
}
```

However when I tried to pass the `callback` to `onChanged` property it wont allow saying
`The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int?)?'.`

```
return DropdownButton<int>(
      value: val,
      onChanged: callback,
    );
```

Comment: can you try changing Function callback to VoidCallback callback

Comment: Tried the VoidCallback and it says `The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int?)?'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like that should work:

```
class JumpDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final int val;
  final void Function(int?)? callback;
  const JumpDropdown({Key? key, required this.val, required this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      value: val,
      onChanged: callback,
    );
  }
}
```

If you need a parameterless callback then it's impossible to assign such a callback directly. You are to use the custom function. Like this:

```
class JumpDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final int val;
  final VoidCallaback callback;
  const JumpDropdown({Key? key, required this.val, required this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      value: val,
      onChanged: (int? v) => callback(),
    );
  }
}
```